# How to override select properties when testing ktor?

Tags: ktor, testcontainers

I'm very new to KTor.

The specific scenario I have involves using Testcontainers with KTor. I want to set the JDBC URL in my KTor configuration using the one from Testcontainers:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
  // The container is running, I have the JDBC URL here
  println("JDBC URL: ${postgresContainer.jdbcUrl}")

  // How do I pass it down to here?
  return testApplication {
    client.get("/people").apply { assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status) }
  }
}
```

Now I know I could use the `environment` option within `testApplication`, but that means configuring my entire environment. I want to keep all the existing properties from my `application.conf` file, but simply replace a handful of select ones.

I know KTor has great support for environment variables, however AFAIK there is no way to set an environment variable at the point in my test code after the Testcontainer has initialized.

I'm wondering what if any options I have here?

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine individual parameters by merging a custom config into the default one. Here is an example:

```
@Test
fun test() = testApplication {
    environment {
        config = config.mergeWith(
            MapApplicationConfig("ktor.deployment.port" to "9090")
        )
    }
    // ...
}
```